# Modify the contents of the memory address of the return of a function

Tags: c, return-value

Is it possible to modify the contents of the memory address of the return value of a function? functions return the value of a locally defined variable.

In the following example, compiled for my machine (x86-64) without warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_val1()
{
  int ret = 1;
  return ret;
}

int get_val2()
{
  int ret = 2;
  return ret;
}

int get_val3()
{
  int ret = 3;
  return ret;
}

void redefine_ints(int *val1, int *val2, int *val3) {
  *val1 = 10;
  *val2 = 11;
  *val3 = 12;
}

void print_and_redefine_ints(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
  printf("val1 %d val2 %d val3 %d\n", val1, val2, val3);
  redefine_ints(&val1, &val2, &val3);
  printf("rval1 %d rval2 %d rval3 %d\n", val1, val2, val3);
}

int main()
{
  print_and_redefine_ints(get_val1(), get_val2(), get_val3());
  return 0;
}
```

I get the next output:

```
val1 1 val2 2 val3 3
rval1 10 rval2 11 rval3 12
```

This is the expected output, but how is it possible? Where are these variables stored?

Comment: `redefine_ints(&val1, &val2, &val3);` here you're passing references to the variables, that's the only point where they get changed.

Comment: You are not modifying the return value of a function directly. `print_and_redefine_ints(get_val1(), get_val2(), get_val3());` Here you pass the return values to another function by value.

Comment: I'm going to rephrase the question. Give me a few minutes to edit it.

Comment: You are not modifying anything that are in `get_val1()`/2/3. But, in `print_and_redefine_ints(int val1, int val2, int val3) { ... }` you are **copying** the return values of the functions (because you are calling this way : `print_and_redefine_ints(get_val1(), get_val2(), get_val3());`) I hope it helps

Comment: The question title and the first sentence of the question don't make much sense

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Indeed; it's not possible to construct what the op *really* wants to ask in standard C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A draw may explain more than some text. I'll use only 1 `get_val1()` in that example.

```
print_and_redefine_ints(get_val1());
                           |
                           |
                         [CALL]
                           |
                           |
                           V
                    int get_val1()
                    {
                        int ret = 1;<----------------------------------------------------+
                        return ret;                                                      |
                    }      |                                                             |
                           |                                                             |
                    [COPY OF VALUE]                                                      |
                           |                                                             |
                           |                                                             |
                           +---+                                                         |
                               |                                                         |
                               |                                                         |
                               V                                                         |
void print_and_redefine_ints(int val1) {                                                 |
    printf("val1 %d\n");        ^                                                        |
    redefine_ints(&val1);       |                                                        |
                    |           +--------------------------------------------+           |
                    |                                                        |           |
          [POINTER AKA REFERENCE]                                            |           |
                    |                                                        |           |
                     |                                                       |           |
                      V                                                      |           |
void redefine_ints(int *val1) {                                              |           |
    *val1 = 10; //<---- the value is changed, then its referenced value (this one, NOT THIS ONE) is changed too
}                     |
                      |
                      +---+
                          |
                    [VALUE CHANGED]
                          |
                          |
                          V
    printf("rval1 %d\n", val1);
    printf("original val1 %d\n", get_val1()); //if you add this line, you'll notice the returned value of get_val1() is still 1
}
```

Comment: It's considered rude *not* to upvote an answer with ASCII art.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is well-defined C.

The *anonymous temporary* `int`s created by `get_val...()` have a lifetime contemporaneous with the entire statement in which they are created.

But note that you take a value copy of each of these `int`s when you call `print_and_redefine_ints` so there's nothing particularly special going on here.

(Note that you would not be able to *bind* pointers to the anonymous temporary `int`s to `int*` function parameters though.)

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it possible to modify the contents of the memory address of the return (value) of a function?*

No, it is not.

However, that is not the case *here*. In your code, the return values of `get_val<n>()` function calls are stored in the function parameters `int val1`, `int val2`, `int val3`. They are local to the called function. The lifetime of those variables are the function execution period.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1,

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [....]

and, from §6.9.1, Function definition,

> Each parameter has automatic storage duration; its identifier is an lvalue

Thus, just like any other local variable, you can modify the content of those variables using their address.